# add data-title attribute to my <td> in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using datatables to give all my tables the jquery datatables magic,
I do my responsive tables by adding data-title to my td's. how can I add the data-title to all my td's so they look like this

```
<td data-title="Fruit">Apple</td>
<td data-title="Good or bad">They are delicious</td>
```

and so on...

I currently have this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contacts').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "src/data.php?form_action=get-table",

    } );
});
```

and my return json looks like this

```
{
"draw":"1",
"recordsTotal":2,
"recordsFiltered":2,
"data":[
  [
     "Apples",
     "They are delicious",
     "2016-10-10 07:47:12",
     "New entry",
     "1"
  ],
  [
     "Bananas",
     "They are also delicious",
     "2016-10-10 07:47:12",
     "New entry",
     "2"
  ]
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use datatables `createdRow` callback. like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contacts').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "src/data.php?form_action=get-table",
        // Per-row function to iterate cells
        "createdRow": function (row, data, rowIndex) {
            // Per-cell function to do whatever needed with cells
            $.each($('td', row), function (colIndex) {
                // For example, adding data-* attributes to the cell
                $(this).attr('data-title', "your cell title");
            });
        }
    });
});
```